# Git ignoring Android Studio project libs folder

Tags: android, git, gitignore

In my current project, I've added a `libs` folder inside my project's `app` directory. inside the libs, I've added an SDK in .aar format. But currently, the problem is that, when I push all my updates into a git repo, all of my updates pushed perfectly, except that `libs` folder. But I need to push that libs folder to the git repo. How I will able to do that. Here is my `.gitignore` file -

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.aar
*.ap_
*.aab

# Files for the ART/Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
out/
#  Uncomment the following line in case you need and you don't have the release build type files in your app
# release/

# Gradle files
.gradle/
build/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties

# Proguard folder generated by Eclipse
proguard/

# Log Files
*.log

# Android Studio Navigation editor temp files
.navigation/

# Android Studio captures folder
captures/

# IntelliJ
*.iml
.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/tasks.xml
.idea/gradle.xml
.idea/assetWizardSettings.xml
.idea/dictionaries
.idea/libraries
.idea/misc.xml
# Android Studio 3 in .gitignore file.
.idea/caches
.idea/modules.xml
# Comment next line if keeping position of elements in Navigation Editor is relevant for you
.idea/navEditor.xml
.idea/

# Keystore files
# Uncomment the following lines if you do not want to check your keystore files in.
#*.jks
#*.keystore

# External native build folder generated in Android Studio 2.2 and later
.externalNativeBuild
.cxx/

# Google Services (e.g. APIs or Firebase)
# google-services.json

# Freeline
freeline.py
freeline/
freeline_project_description.json

# fastlane
fastlane/report.xml
fastlane/Preview.html
fastlane/screenshots
fastlane/test_output
fastlane/readme.md

# Version control
vcs.xml

# lint
lint/intermediates/
lint/generated/
lint/outputs/
lint/tmp/
# lint/reports/
```

What should I do now to resolve this issue?

[image: Here libs directory placing image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
git add --force <path_to_libs>
```

or add in .gitignore:

```
!<path_to_libs>
```

the "!" makes git do not ignore libs, as by default it is ignoring.

Answer (score 1):

We need to add some lines in gitIgnore file for ignore the specific file and folder push on GitHub

Here is the android project's gitIgnore file:-

```
#built application files
*.apk
*.ap_
*.aab
                           
# files for the dex VM
*.dex
                            
# Java class files
*.class
                            
# generated files
bin/
gen/
                            
# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
                        
# Windows thumbnail db
Thumbs.db
                
# OSX files
.DS_Store
                            
# Android Studio
*.iml
.idea
#.idea/workspace.xml - remove # and delete .idea if it better suit your needs.
.gradle
build/
.navigation
captures/
output.json 
    
#NDK
obj/
.externalNativeBuild
```

Here is some other files and folder if the still these files showing on commit section. then add these lines also:-

```
*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures
.externalNativeBuild
```

Answer (score 0):

And how exactly is that `.gitignore` file related to Android Studio ??

The only way to provide a local AAR dependency is a local `flatDir` repository.